# How does inlining work in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, inlining

I am trying to understand how llvm inlining work (Inliner class). The operation that I don't understand is the follow:

```
SmallVector<std::pair<CallSite, int>, 16> CallSites;
```

when SmallVector is an llvm class. In particular I don't understand what is the function of "16" in this code..

Comment: First google hit maybe? http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SmallVector.html? Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a `SmallVector` of 16 elements, each element being a `std::pair<CallSite, int>`.

edit: As Eli has correctly pointed out, SmallVector can be dynamically resized. 16 is just the built-in size (this means that storing up to 16 elements doesn't incur in any heap allocations).

Comment: Careful - this may be wrong - what do you mean by "of 16 elements"? 16 is a *hint* saying what is the typical maximal number of elements expected, but the vector may grow to any size. This hint allows SmallVector to pre-allocate some elements on the stack, avoiding expensive heap allocations

Comment: "16" is within the generics, can't it be a SmallVector within a SmallVector?